# How to print vertical histogram of this code using only for loops in c++?

Tags: c++

```
//Program to Print Horizontal Histogram of Shape{*} 

#include<"iostream">

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a[100],n,i,j;

    cout<<"Enter Size of Array"<<endl;
    cin>>n;

    cout<<"Enter Array Elemnts"<<endl;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        cin>>a[i];
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<a[i];j++) {
            cout<<"* ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

This code is printing the histogram in horizontal direction, but I want to print it in vertical direction from bottom to top.

Comment: _`#include<"iostream">`_ is wrong. It should be `#include<iostream>`

Comment: Adding just code won't help. Explain what you want to do clearly?

Comment: please help me to sort out of this coding............

Comment: The solution depends on whether you want columns pointing upwards or downwards.

Answer (score 1):

The solution depends on wether the columns shall point downwards or upwards. Beside of this the solution is similar:

The outer loop iterates through rows. The inner loop iterates throuh columns as well as the corresponding array elements. If the value is smaller than current row than print a solid character otherwise a space.

For the number of necessary rows, the maximum value in array must be known. For the upwards pointing columns, this must be determined beforehands as it is the start value for iteration in outer loop.

My sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
  int n = 10; // size of array
  std::vector<int> a; // array elements
  int maxA = 15;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) a.push_back(rand() % maxA);
  // print values
  for (int value : a) std::cout << ' ' << value;
  std::cout << '\n';
  // determine max height of columns
  maxA = 0;
  for (int value : a) if (maxA < value) maxA = value;
  // output maxA lines
  for (; maxA > 0; --maxA) {
    for (int value : a) std::cout << (value >= maxA ? " #" : "  ");
    std::cout << '\n';
  }
  // done
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
 13 1 12 10 8 10 1 12 9 1
 #                  
 #   #         #    
 #   #         #    
 #   # #   #   #    
 #   # #   #   # #  
 #   # # # #   # #  
 #   # # # #   # #  
 #   # # # #   # #  
 #   # # # #   # #  
 #   # # # #   # #  
 #   # # # #   # #  
 #   # # # #   # #  
 # # # # # # # # # #
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/970db7c872ef9935)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

## include<"iostream">

using namespace std;

int main()

{

```
int a[100],i,j,n,max,copy;

cout<<"Enter the size of Array:"<<endl;
cin>>n;


for(i=0;i<n;i++)

{

    cout<<"Enter the element:"<<i+1<<endl;
    cin>>a[i];
}

//finding max no.
max=a[0];
for(i=0;i<n;i++)

{
    if(a[i]>max)

        max=a[i];
}
copy=max;

 //logic for vertical histogram

cout<<"**********HISTOGRAM**********"<<endl;

for(i=0;i<copy;i++,max--)

{
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)

    {
        if(a[j]>=max)
            cout<<" * ";
        else
            cout<<"   ";
    }

    cout<<"\n";
}
```

}